# Error: "package test is not a value" using scalatest FunSpec

Tags: scala, scalatest

I changed a test from `WordMatchers` to `FunSpec` and now can not rid the tests of the following compilation error:

```
class SangriaDnbIACDataPipelineTest extends FunSpec {

  test("SangriaDnbIACDataPipeline") {
    val args =
```

[image]

```
 error: package test is not a value
[ERROR]   test("SangriaDnbIACDataPipeline") {
```

This is on `scala 2.11` with `scalatest 3.0.1`.

Comment: Have you named your package "test"?

Comment: The accepted answer essentially states that you should use `FunSuite` instead of `FunSpec`. I assume that `FunSuite` has a method `test`. But that's not what I asked. I asked whether you named your package (or one of the parent packages) "test". If this is not the case, then the error message is really strange, and should be reported elsewhere.

Comment: no - the package is not `test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the FunSuite extension:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class SangriaDnbIACDataPipelineTest extends FunSuite {

  test("SangriaDnbIACDataPipeline") {
    val args =
```

See the [testing styles](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/selecting_a_style)